# Serilog only logs messages from Main() into Loggly, in .NET Framework

Tags: .net, logging, serilog, loggly

I have an app written in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and we're using Serilog to log messages into Loggly.

The issue I have, which I cannot figure out, is that it only logs messages from the Main() method, and does not log messages from other methods down below (or maybe it only logs the very first messages).

I.e. I have a code:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.AppSettings().Enrich.FromLogContext().WriteTo.Loggly(
            logglyConfig: new LogglyConfiguration
            {
                ApplicationName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Loggly.ApplicationName"],
                CustomerToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Loggly.CustomerToken"],
                Tags = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Loggly.Tags"].Split(',').ToList(),
                EndpointHostName = "xxx.loggly.com",
                EndpointPort = 443,
                IsEnabled = true,
                LogTransport = TransportProtocol.Https,
                ThrowExceptions = false,
                OmitTimestamp = false
            }).CreateLogger();
        Log.Information($"[{nameof(Program)}] Starting...");
        
        Execute();
      }

      public static void Execute()
      {
        Log.Information($"Executing [{nameof(Program)}] ...");

        *... some processing code here ...*
        
        Print();
      }

      public static void Print()
      {
          Log.Information($"Printing Data");

          *... some printing code here ...*
      }
```

But in the Loggly I only get the first Log ("*Starting...*"), and none of the others ("*Executing*" and "*Printing*").

Any thoughts on what is wrong here or what am I missing?

Comment: one note: using string interpolation `Log.Information($"Text {value}")` is not compatible with Serilog and/or modern structured logging, you need to make it explicitly `Log.Information("Text {value}", value)` - serilog.net presents a good tutorial on these concepts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinks like the Loggly sink send messages on a background thread. If your application ends before the background thread was able to send the messages, they are lost and that is likely what's happening in your case...

It's your responsibility to flush the logs before your application ends. See [Lifecycle of Loggers](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers).

You do that by calling `Log.CloseAndFlush()` or by disposing your logger.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        // ...
        .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush(); // <##<##<##<##<##<##
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @C. Augusto Proiete. Looks like this can address some part of my issue. I see more messages now, but not all. I will need to dig deeper into it.

Comment: @KVN You might want to enable [SelfLog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog) and see if any errors are being reported by the sink